# Webpage view source has body content as 'please wait' and selenium is unable to load any elements

Tags: selenium

I've a webpage where if I use inspect element (or inspect frame), I get only 'Please wait, this page is loading...' even though the chrome page is completely loaded (and the frame is also loaded completely). I've clicked on Inspect element after the page load and when querying in 'console', I get the html elements (see in screenshot).

While checking in selenium with below code, the returned list value is empty (because the page source has only 'please wait...' message???) even though the console returns the elements.

Is there a work around? I know I'm missing something but have spent about 2hrs already. So, reaching out to you guys.

**Inspect Element (Ctrl+Shift+I)**

[image: Console Output]

**View Source (Ctrl+U)**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=10, user-scalable=yes">
<script type="text/javascript">......some script.........</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="apploading" class="loadingCls">Please wait, this page is loading...</div>
    <iframe id="docsFileIframe" name="docsFileIframe" method="POST"
        style="display: none;"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

**Selenium Script**

```
List<WebElement> tiles = driver.findElements( By.className("swiftux-tiles"));

System.out.println("Tiles value "+ tiles);
```

---

**[Update for @Dev]**

**Code**

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;


public class testSelenium {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String url = "";
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "\\Desktop\\Mathes\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get(url);
        String currentURL = driver.getCurrentUrl();
        System.out.println(currentURL);
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println("Page Source: \n "+driver.getPageSource());
        List<WebElement> tiles = driver.findElements( By.className("swiftux-tiles"));
        System.out.println("Tiles List"+ tiles);
    }
}
```

**Console Output**

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9) on port 14929
Only local connections are allowed.
May 02, 2017 5:42:23 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
May 02, 2017 5:42:26 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS

Page Source: 
 <!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=10, user-scalable=yes" />

<title>CITI Workflow Management</title>

<style>
body {
    background-color: #D3D3D3;
}

.loadingCls {
    border: 0px solid red;
    width: 30%;
    margin: 5% auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: black;
}

.portal-home {
    background-image:
        url(../icons/house.png)
        !important;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/Constants.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">var Ext=Ext||{};Ext.manifest=Ext.manifest||"app.json";Ext=Ext||{};
Ext.Boot=Ext.Boot||function(j){function k(a){if(a.$isRequest)return a;a=a.url?a:{url:a};var b=a.url;p(a,{urls:b.charAt?[b]:b,charset:a.charset||d.config.charset});p(this,a)}function r(a){if(a.$isEntry)return a;var b=a.charset||d.config.charset,c=Ext.manifest,c=c&amp;&amp;c.loader,e=void 0!==a.cache?a.cache:c&amp;&amp;c.cache,m;void 0===e&amp;&amp;(e=!d.config.disableCaching);!1===e?m=+new Date:!0!==e&amp;&amp;(m=e);m&amp;&amp;(c=c&amp;&amp;c.cacheParam||d.config.disableCachingParam,m=c+"\x3d"+m);p(a,{charset:b,buster:m,requests:[]});p(this,a)}
var h=document,f=function(a,b,c){c&amp;&amp;f(a,c);if(a&amp;&amp;b&amp;&amp;"object"==typeof b)for(var e in b)a[e]=b[e];return a},t={disableCaching:/[?&amp;](?:cache|disableCacheBuster)\b/i.test(location.search)||!/http[s]?\:/i.test(location.href)||/(^|[ ;])ext-cache=1/.test(h.cookie)?!1:!0,disableCachingParam:"_dc",loadDelay:!1,preserveScripts:!0,charset:void 0},v=/\.css(?:\?|$)/i,u=h.createElement("a"),q="undefined"!==typeof window,s={browser:q,node:!q&amp;&amp;"function"===typeof require,phantom:"undefined"!==typeof phantom&amp;&amp;phantom.fs},
n=Ext.platformTags={},p=function(a,b,c){c&amp;&amp;p(a,c);if(a&amp;&amp;b&amp;&amp;"object"===typeof b)for(var e in b)a[e]=b[e];return a},d={loading:0,loaded:0,env:s,config:t,scripts:{},currentFile:null,suspendedQueue:[],currentRequest:null,syncMode:!1,useElements:!0,listeners:[],Request:k,Entry:r,detectPlatformTags:function(){var a=navigator.userAgent,b=n.isMobile=/Mobile(\/|\s)/.test(a),c,e,m,l;c=document.createElement("div");e="iPhone;iPod;Android;Silk;Android 2;BlackBerry;BB;iPad;RIM Tablet OS;MSIE 10;Trident;Chrome;Tizen;Firefox;Safari;Windows Phone".split(";");
var g={};m=e.length;var w;for(w=0;w&lt;m;w++)l=e[w],g[l]=RegExp(l).test(a);b=g.iPhone||g.iPod||!g.Silk&amp;&amp;g.Android&amp;&amp;(g["Android 2"]||b)||(g.BlackBerry||g.BB)&amp;&amp;g.isMobile||g["Windows Phone"];a=!n.isPhone&amp;&amp;(g.iPad||g.Android||g.Silk||g["RIM Tablet OS"]||g["MSIE 10"]&amp;&amp;/; Touch/.test(a));e="ontouchend"in c;!e&amp;&amp;(c.setAttribute&amp;&amp;c.removeAttribute)&amp;&amp;(c.setAttribute("ontouchend",""),e="function"===typeof c.ontouchend,"undefined"!==typeof c.ontouchend&amp;&amp;(c.ontouchend=void 0),c.removeAttribute("ontouchend"));e=
e||navigator.maxTouchPoints||navigator.msMaxTouchPoints;c=!b&amp;&amp;!a;m=g["MSIE 10"];l=g.Blackberry||g.BB;f(n,d.loadPlatformsParam(),{phone:b,tablet:a,desktop:c,touch:e,ios:g.iPad||g.iPhone||g.iPod,android:g.Android||g.Silk,blackberry:l,safari:g.Safari&amp;&amp;!l,chrome:g.Chrome,ie10:m,windows:m||g.Trident,tizen:g.Tizen,firefox:g.Firefox})},loadPlatformsParam:function(){var a=window.location.search.substr(1).split("\x26"),b={},c,e,d;for(c=0;c&lt;a.length;c++)e=a[c].split("\x3d"),b[e[0]]=e[1];if(b.platformTags){e=
b.platform.split(/\W/);a=e.length;for(c=0;c&lt;a;c++)d=e[c].split(":")}return d},filterPlatform:function(a){a=[].concat(a);var b,c,e;b=a.length;for(c=0;c&lt;b;c++)if(e=a[c],n.hasOwnProperty(e))return!!n[e];return!1},init:function(){var a=h.getElementsByTagName("script"),b=a.length,c=/\/ext(\-[a-z\-]+)?\.js$/,e,m,l,g,f,x;for(x=0;x&lt;b;x++)if(m=(e=a[x]).src)l=e.readyState||null,!g&amp;&amp;c.test(m)&amp;&amp;(d.hasReadyState="readyState"in e,d.hasAsync="async"in e||!d.hasReadyState,g=m),d.scripts[f=d.canonicalUrl(m)]||new r({key:f,
url:m,done:null===l||"loaded"===l||"complete"===l,el:e,prop:"src"});g||(e=a[a.length-1],g=e.src,d.hasReadyState="readyState"in e,d.hasAsync="async"in e||!d.hasReadyState);d.baseUrl=g.substring(0,g.lastIndexOf("/")+1);d.origin=window.location.origin||window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.hostname+(window.location.port?":"+window.location.port:"");d.detectPlatformTags();Ext.filterPlatform=d.filterPlatform},canonicalUrl:function(a){u.href=a;a=u.href;var b=t.disableCachingParam,b=b?a.indexOf(b+
"\x3d"):-1,c,e;if(0&lt;b&amp;&amp;("?"===(c=a.charAt(b-1))||"\x26"===c)){e=a.indexOf("\x26",b);if((e=0&gt;e?"":a.substring(e))&amp;&amp;"?"===c)++b,e=e.substring(1);a=a.substring(0,b-1)+e}return a},getConfig:function(a){return a?d.config[a]:d.config},setConfig:function(a,b){if("string"===typeof a)d.config[a]=b;else for(var c in a)d.setConfig(c,a[c]);return d},getHead:function(){return d.docHead||(d.docHead=h.head||h.getElementsByTagName("head")[0])},create:function(a,b,c){c=c||{};c.url=a;c.key=b;return d.scripts[b]=new r(c)},
getEntry:function(a,b){var c=d.canonicalUrl(a),e=d.scripts[c];e||(e=d.create(a,c,b));return e},processRequest:function(a,b){a.loadEntries(b)},load:function(a){a=new k(a);if(a.sync||d.syncMode)return d.loadSync(a);d.currentRequest?(a.getEntries(),d.suspendedQueue.push(a)):(d.currentRequest=a,d.processRequest(a,!1));return d},loadSync:function(a){a=new k(a);d.syncMode++;d.processRequest(a,!0);d.syncMode--;return d},loadBasePrefix:function(a){a=new k(a);a.prependBaseUrl=!0;return d.load(a)},loadSyncBasePrefix:function(a){a=
new k(a);a.prependBaseUrl=!0;return d.loadSync(a)},requestComplete:function(a){if(d.currentRequest===a)for(d.currentRequest=null;0&lt;d.suspendedQueue.length;)if(a=d.suspendedQueue.shift(),!a.done){d.load(a);break}!d.currentRequest&amp;&amp;0==d.suspendedQueue.length&amp;&amp;d.fireListeners()},isLoading:function(){return!d.currentRequest&amp;&amp;0==d.suspendedQueue.length},fireListeners:function(){for(var a;d.isLoading()&amp;&amp;(a=d.listeners.shift());)a()},onBootReady:function(a){d.isLoading()?d.listeners.push(a):a()},getPathsFromIndexes:function(a,
b){return k.prototype.getPathsFromIndexes(a,b)},createLoadOrderMap:function(a){return k.prototype.createLoadOrderMap(a)},fetch:function(a,b,c,e){e=void 0===e?!!b:e;var d=new XMLHttpRequest,l,g,f,h=!1,j=function(){d&amp;&amp;4==d.readyState&amp;&amp;(g=1223===d.status?204:0===d.status&amp;&amp;("file:"===(self.location||{}).protocol||"ionp:"===(self.location||{}).protocol)?200:d.status,f=d.responseText,l={content:f,status:g,exception:h},b&amp;&amp;b.call(c,l),d=null)};e&amp;&amp;(d.onreadystatechange=j);try{d.open("GET",a,e),d.send(null)}catch(k){return h=
k,j(),l}e||j();return l},notifyAll:function(a){a.notifyRequests()}};k.prototype={$isRequest:!0,createLoadOrderMap:function(a){var b=a.length,c={},e,d;for(e=0;e&lt;b;e++)d=a[e],c[d.path]=d;return c},getLoadIndexes:function(a,b,c,e,m){var l=c[a],g,f,h,j,k;if(b[a])return b;b[a]=!0;for(a=!1;!a;){h=!1;for(j in b)if(b.hasOwnProperty(j)&amp;&amp;(l=c[j]))if(f=this.prepareUrl(l.path),f=d.getEntry(f),!m||!f||!f.done){f=l.requires;e&amp;&amp;l.uses&amp;&amp;(f=f.concat(l.uses));l=f.length;for(g=0;g&lt;l;g++)k=f[g],b[k]||(h=b[k]=!0)}h||
(a=!0)}return b},getPathsFromIndexes:function(a,b){var c=[],e=[],d,f;for(d in a)a.hasOwnProperty(d)&amp;&amp;a[d]&amp;&amp;c.push(d);c.sort(function(a,b){return a-b});d=c.length;for(f=0;f&lt;d;f++)e.push(b[c[f]].path);return e},expandUrl:function(a,b,c,e){"string"==typeof a&amp;&amp;(a=[a]);var d=this.loadOrder,f=this.loadOrderMap;if(d){this.loadOrderMap=f=f||this.createLoadOrderMap(d);b=b||{};var g=a.length,h=[],j,k;for(j=0;j&lt;g;j++)(k=f[a[j]])?this.getLoadIndexes(k.idx,b,d,c,e):h.push(a[j]);return this.getPathsFromIndexes(b,
d).concat(h)}return a},expandUrls:function(a,b){"string"==typeof a&amp;&amp;(a=[a]);var c=[],d={},f,l=a.length,g,h,j,k;for(g=0;g&lt;l;g++){f=this.expandUrl(a[g],{},b,!0);h=0;for(j=f.length;h&lt;j;h++)k=f[h],d[k]||(d[k]=!0,c.push(k))}0==c.length&amp;&amp;(c=a);return c},expandLoadOrder:function(){var a=this.urls,b;this.expanded?b=a:(b=this.expandUrls(a,!0),this.expanded=!0);this.urls=b;a.length!=b.length&amp;&amp;(this.sequential=!0);return this},getUrls:function(){this.expandLoadOrder();return this.urls},prepareUrl:function(a){return this.prependBaseUrl?
d.baseUrl+a:a},getEntries:function(){var a=this.entries,b,c,e;if(!a){a=[];e=this.getUrls();for(b=0;b&lt;e.length;b++)c=this.prepareUrl(e[b]),c=d.getEntry(c,{buster:this.buster,charset:this.charset}),c.requests.push(this),a.push(c);this.entries=a}return a},loadEntries:function(a){var b=this,c=b.getEntries(),d=c.length,f=b.loadStart||0,h,g;void 0!==a&amp;&amp;(b.sync=a);b.loaded=b.loaded||0;b.loading=b.loading||d;for(g=f;g&lt;d;g++)if(h=c[g],f=h.loaded?!0:c[g].load(b.sync),!f){b.loadStart=g;h.onDone(function(){b.loadEntries(a)});
break}b.processLoadedEntries()},processLoadedEntries:function(){var a=this.getEntries(),b=a.length,c=this.startIndex||0,d;if(!this.done){for(;c&lt;b;c++){d=a[c];if(!d.loaded){this.startIndex=c;return}d.evaluated||d.evaluate();d.error&amp;&amp;(this.error=!0)}this.notify()}},notify:function(){var a=this;if(!a.done){var b=a.error,c=a[b?"failure":"success"],b="delay"in a?a.delay:b?1:d.config.chainDelay,e=a.scope||a;a.done=!0;c&amp;&amp;(0===b||0&lt;b?setTimeout(function(){c.call(e,a)},b):c.call(e,a));a.fireListeners();d.requestComplete(a)}},
onDone:function(a){var b=this.listeners||(this.listeners=[]);this.done?a(this):b.push(a)},fireListeners:function(){var a=this.listeners,b;if(a)for(;b=a.shift();)b(this)}};r.prototype={$isEntry:!0,done:!1,evaluated:!1,loaded:!1,isCrossDomain:function(){void 0===this.crossDomain&amp;&amp;(this.crossDomain=0!==this.getLoadUrl().indexOf(d.origin));return this.crossDomain},isCss:function(){void 0===this.css&amp;&amp;(this.css=this.url&amp;&amp;v.test(this.url));return this.css},getElement:function(a){var b=this.el;b||(this.isCss()?
(a=a||"link",b=h.createElement(a),"link"==a?(b.rel="stylesheet",this.prop="href"):this.prop="textContent",b.type="text/css"):(b=h.createElement(a||"script"),b.type="text/javascript",this.prop="src",d.hasAsync&amp;&amp;(b.async=!1)),this.el=b);return b},getLoadUrl:function(){var a=d.canonicalUrl(this.url);this.loadUrl||(this.loadUrl=this.buster?a+(-1===a.indexOf("?")?"?":"\x26")+this.buster:a);return this.loadUrl},fetch:function(a){var b=this.getLoadUrl();d.fetch(b,a.complete,this,!!a.async)},onContentLoaded:function(a){var b=
a.status,c=a.content;a=a.exception;this.getLoadUrl();this.loaded=!0;(a||0===b)&amp;&amp;!s.phantom?this.evaluated=this.error=!0:200&lt;=b&amp;&amp;300&gt;b||304===b||s.phantom||0===b&amp;&amp;0&lt;c.length?this.content=c:this.evaluated=this.error=!0},createLoadElement:function(a){var b=this,c=b.getElement();b.preserve=!0;c.onerror=function(){b.error=!0;a&amp;&amp;a()};d.hasReadyState?c.onreadystatechange=function(){("loaded"===this.readyState||"complete"===this.readyState)&amp;&amp;a&amp;&amp;a()}:c.onload=a;c[b.prop]=b.getLoadUrl()},onLoadElementReady:function(){d.getHead().appendChild(this.getElement());
this.evaluated=!0},inject:function(a){var b=d.getHead(),c=this.url,e=this.key,f,j;this.isCss()?(this.preserve=!0,j=e.substring(0,e.lastIndexOf("/")+1),f=h.createElement("base"),f.href=j,b.firstChild?b.insertBefore(f,b.firstChild):b.appendChild(f),f.href=f.href,c&amp;&amp;(a+="\n/*# sourceURL\x3d"+e+" */"),c=this.getElement("style"),e="styleSheet"in c,b.appendChild(f),e?(b.appendChild(c),c.styleSheet.cssText=a):(c.textContent=a,b.appendChild(c)),b.removeChild(f)):(c&amp;&amp;(a+="\n//# sourceURL\x3d"+e),Ext.globalEval(a));
return this},loadCrossDomain:function(){var a=this,b=function(){a.loaded=a.evaluated=a.done=!0;a.notifyRequests()};if(a.isCss())a.createLoadElement(),a.evaluateLoadElement(),b();else return a.createLoadElement(function(){b()}),a.evaluateLoadElement(),!1;return!0},loadElement:function(){var a=this;if(a.isCss())return a.loadCrossDomain();a.createLoadElement(function(){a.loaded=a.evaluated=a.done=!0;a.notifyRequests()});a.evaluateLoadElement();return!0},loadSync:function(){var a=this;a.fetch({async:!1,
complete:function(b){a.onContentLoaded(b)}});a.evaluate();a.notifyRequests()},load:function(a){var b=this;if(!b.loaded){if(b.loading)return!1;b.loading=!0;if(a)b.loadSync();else{if(b.isCrossDomain())return b.loadCrossDomain();if(!b.isCss()&amp;&amp;d.hasReadyState)b.createLoadElement(function(){b.loaded=!0;b.notifyRequests()});else{if(d.useElements)return b.loadElement();b.fetch({async:!a,complete:function(a){b.onContentLoaded(a);b.notifyRequests()}})}}}return!0},evaluateContent:function(){this.inject(this.content);
this.content=null},evaluateLoadElement:function(){d.getHead().appendChild(this.getElement())},evaluate:function(){!this.evaluated&amp;&amp;!this.evaluating&amp;&amp;(this.evaluating=!0,void 0!==this.content?this.evaluateContent():this.error||this.evaluateLoadElement(),this.evaluated=this.done=!0,this.cleanup())},cleanup:function(){var a=this.el,b;if(a){if(!this.preserve)for(b in this.el=null,a.parentNode.removeChild(a),a)try{b!==this.prop&amp;&amp;(a[b]=null),delete a[b]}catch(c){}a.onload=a.onerror=a.onreadystatechange=
j}},notifyRequests:function(){var a=this.requests,b=a.length,c,d;for(c=0;c&lt;b;c++)d=a[c],d.processLoadedEntries();this.done&amp;&amp;this.fireListeners()},onDone:function(a){var b=this.listeners||(this.listeners=[]);this.done?a(this):b.push(a)},fireListeners:function(){var a=this.listeners,b;if(a&amp;&amp;0&lt;a.length)for(;b=a.shift();)b(this)}};Ext.disableCacheBuster=function(a,b){var c=new Date;c.setTime(c.getTime()+864E5*(a?3650:-1));c=c.toGMTString();h.cookie="ext-cache\x3d1; expires\x3d"+c+"; path\x3d"+(b||"/")};
d.init();return d}(function(){});Ext.globalEval=Ext.globalEval||(this.execScript?function(j){execScript(j)}:function(j){eval.call(window,j)});Function.prototype.bind||function(){var j=Array.prototype.slice,k=function(k){var h=j.call(arguments,1),f=this;if(h.length)return function(){var t=arguments;return f.apply(k,t.length?h.concat(j.call(t)):h)};h=null;return function(){return f.apply(k,arguments)}};Function.prototype.bind=k;k.$extjs=!0}();Ext=Ext||window.Ext||{};
Ext.Microloader=Ext.Microloader||function(){var j=Ext.Boot,k=[],r=!1,h={detectPlatformTags:function(){Ext.beforeLoad&amp;&amp;Ext.beforeLoad(Ext.platformTags)},initPlatformTags:function(){h.detectPlatformTags()},init:function(){h.initPlatformTags();var f=Ext._beforereadyhandler;Ext._beforereadyhandler=function(){Ext.Boot!==j&amp;&amp;(Ext.apply(Ext.Boot,j),Ext.Boot=j);f&amp;&amp;f()}},run:function(){h.init();var f=Ext.manifest;if("string"===typeof f){var k=f.indexOf(".json")===f.length-5?f:f+".json";j.fetch(k,function(j){f=
Ext.manifest=JSON.parse(j.content);h.load(f)})}else h.load(f)},load:function(f){var k=f.loadOrder,v=k?j.createLoadOrderMap(k):null,u=[],q=f.js||[],s=f.css||[],n,p=function(){r=!0;h.notify()};k&amp;&amp;(f.loadOrderMap=v);for(var d=s.concat(q),s=d.length,q=0;q&lt;s;q++)f=d[q],n=!0,f.platform&amp;&amp;!j.filterPlatform(f.platform)&amp;&amp;(n=!1),n&amp;&amp;u.push(f.path);j.load({url:u,loadOrder:k,loadOrderMap:v,sequential:!0,success:p,failure:p})},onMicroloaderReady:function(f){r?f():k.push(f)},notify:function(){for(var f;f=k.shift();)f()}};
return h}();Ext.manifest=Ext.manifest||"bootstrap";Ext.Microloader.run();</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="apploading" class="loadingCls">Please wait, this page is loading...</div>
    <iframe id="docsFileIframe" name="docsFileIframe" method="POST" style="display: none;"></iframe>


</body></html>
Tiles List[]
```

---

**Update for Kushal**

[image: Inspect Element]

Comment: If it is a public website can share the url? Share your exact testing steps as well.

Comment: It's not a public URL. Testing steps are simple.Load ChromeDriver(), then driver.get(url). Then pageLoadTimeout for waiting. Now, List the webelements (tiles) and nothing is found. When I do an 'Inspect Element', I see the html elements. But 'View Source' shows only 'please wait...' in body tag.

Comment: petty absurd, can't comment without looking at the proper HTML DOM or URL.

Comment: @Dev added the complete code. Do let me know if you need any info. The HTML DOM is in the output.

Comment: I'm getting that from 'Inspect Element' @kushal. It's in the image [link]https://i.stack.imgur.com/feXKu.jpg

Comment: @Matheswaran Kanagarajan : this is because for `<iframe> `tag : `style="display: none;"` is present. Are you able to see the said `<ul>` element on front end.

Comment: could you show a snapshot from frontend?

Comment: @kushal., yes, I'm able to see the <ul> elements in front end and shows in inspect element. Is there a way to change 'display: none;' without changing the backend code (well.. code is written by another team).

Comment: That is possible using javascriptexecutor

Comment: Could you please show the snapshot of inspect element for your webelement

Comment: @kushal. here it is https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VID7.jpg. How is javascriptexecutor helpful here?

Comment: javascriptexecutor  won't be helpful here. Print & share output of `System.out.println(tiles.size());`

Comment: @kushal. - the output is 0

Comment: your element seems to be on an `<iframe>` so before `List<WebEelment> tiles =` line; you have to switch to this frame using `driver.switchTo.frame(driver.findElement(By.id("docsFileIframe" ));`